# Geodetic number of Qn

Tags: graph-theory

I know that the Geodetic number of the $Q_n$ ( Hypercube ) graph is 2. Also, the two elements in $V(Q_n)$ which they are differ in all position will make a geodetic set of the graph. But, how to prove ? , how can I show all paths from the two elements as stated above will pass all the elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By your question, I'm assuming you are identifying $V(Q_n)$ with the binary sequences of length $n$. Let $v_0$ and $v_n$ be two vertices who differ in every entry. What you need to consider is that a shortest path from $v_0$ to $v_n$ corresponds to a sequence $(v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ of vertices where $v_{i}$ differs from $v_{i-1}$ in exactly one entry (i.e., $v_i$ and $v_{i-1}$ are adjacent) and for every entry there is exactly one pair $v_i, v_{i-1}$ differing in that entry.

In other, perhaps vaguer, words, a shortest path is just a sequence of $n$ "bit flips" where each "entry/bit" is flipped exactly once.

Given that, can you now see each vertex is in *some* shortest path from $v_1$ to $v_n$? It might be easier to see this if you take $v_0=(0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $v_n=(1,1,\ldots,1)$.